# Why are split coequalizers "contractible"?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-colimits, monads

In the book *Toposes, Triples and Theories* by Barr and Wells, the authors define a contractible coequalizer (elsewhere known as a split coequalizer) to be a commutative diagram:
$A \rightrightarrows_{d^0}^{d^1} B \to^d C$, together with maps $A \leftarrow^t B \leftarrow^sC$ satifying:

1. $d^0 \circ t = id_B$
2. $d^1 \circ t = s \circ d$
3. $d \circ s = id_C$

Now, the definition of $s,t$  feel a lot like a "contracting homotopy", which probably is what motivates their terminology, but I would like to make this more precise. That is, I would like to interpret this definition  simplicially, as saying something about the nerve of the relevant diagrams. Can someone show me how this works?

I'm not firm on necessarily using nerves, but I'd like an explicit connection with simplicial/topological things. A test of how good the connection is might be:  can you extend the definition of contractible coequalizer to other diagrams/colimits?   I'm open to  overly-sophisticated technology,  so if this has a particularly nice phrasing in some sort of $\infty$ categorical world, let me know. I'm also open to any philosophical musings about how the topological interpretation of a coequalizer fits into the Beck monadicity theorem.

Comment: It is in fact part of the data of a contracting homotopy. Of course, to really make sense of this you would need to extend your original diagram to a augmented simplicial object. But note that there is not really a connection with homotopy theory – this is by chance, if you like.